# Scrapping list of binance launchpad coins with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, binance

I am trying to scrape the table to get the list of coins driver.find_element. I tried inspecting the page but I can't find the element for the table. How do I scrape this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 
driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/markets/coinInfo-Launchpool?p=1")
 
# get element
element = driver.find_element(By.ID ,"css-15owl46")
```

Comment: Please add more details to the post such as the code snippets you've tried and the error you are getting along with supporting materials so that others can help you